# Trip Interruption insurance vs. Trip Cancellation insurance: what's the difference?

Tags: travel, insurance, terminology

My credit card says they offer trip interruption insurance as a benefit. I am only familiar with trip cancellation insurance. Are these the same or different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this very succinct answer at [Squaremouth](http://blogs.squaremouth.com/travel-advice/what-is-the-difference-between-trip-cancellation-and-trip-interruption/) (travel insurance comparison site):

> The “trip cancellation” benefit covers you in the event you have to cancel your trip due to a covered reason listed in your travel insurance policy prior to your departure date. Trip interruption benefit covers you in the event you have to interrupt your trip for the same covered reasons after your departure date, but before your scheduled return date.

You should definitely check the specific policy's terms and conditions though, because there is a lot of conflicting info out there.